# Cellular basis of $KW(B_2)$

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, coxeter-groups, hecke-algebras, kazhdan-lusztig

Take $K$ a field. Let $W(B_2)$ be the coxeter group of type $B_2$ with a set $\{s_0,s_1\}$ of generators. Then $W(B_2)=\{1, s_0,s_1,s_0s_1,s_1s_0,s_0s_1s_0, s_1s_0s_1,s_1s_0s_1s_0\}$. I know that the elements of $W(B_2)$ correspond the same shape pairs of standard bitableaux.

Similar to cellular basis of $KS_n$, we have 
\begin{align}
& C_{1} = 1, \quad C_{s_1} = 1 + s_1,  \quad C_{s_0} = 1 + s_0, \quad
C_{s_0s_1} = 1 +s_0+ s_1 + s_0s_1, \\
& C_{s_1s_0} = 1 + s_1 +s_0 + s_1s_0, \quad C_{s_0s_1s_0} = 1 + s_0+ s_1 + s_0s_1 + s_1 s_0 +s_0s_1s_0,\\
& C_{s_1s_0s_1} = 1 + s_1 +s_0 + s_1s_0+ s_0s_1 + s_1s_0s_1, \\
& C_{s_1s_0s_1s_0} = 1 + s_1 +s_0 + s_1s_0+ s_0s_1 + s_1s_0s_1+ s_0s_1s_0 + s_1s_0s_1s_0.
\end{align}
But $\{C_w \mid w \in W(B_2)\}$ is not a cellular basis of $KW(B_2)$. What is cellular basis of $KW(B_2)$?